# How to create a link between Git and NPM

Tags: node.js, github, npm

Is there a way to link GitHub with Node Package Manager?
So that if changes are pushed in Git they are also published in NPM.

Answer (score 1):

Travis-CI will definitely handle this for you.

http://mclear.co.uk/2013/10/06/publishing-to-npm-on-git-commit-using-github-hooks-and-travis/

There's also this gist, but you'll have to see whether it works yourself.

https://gist.github.com/fent/3140668

If not you can use it as the basis for your own solution using got post hooks.